# Rails Thinking Sphinx Indexing Self Join Associations Tree Structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tree, indexing, associations, thinking-sphinx

I have products which belong to a category. And categories make up a tree 
structure by having a parent and children using self joins:

Associations:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "parent_id"
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Category"
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

For example,

```
Fruits & Vegetables     =>    "High" Category 
Fresh Fruits            =>    "Intermediate" Category
Citrus                  =>    "Low" Category
Limes Large             =>    Product
```

I would like to use Thinking Sphinx to index both the "low" category name and 
"high" category name for a product, and possibly even all category names in between in the tree hierarchy.

I had no trouble indexing the low category parent name as follows:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  indexes :name
  indexes category.parent.name, as: :low_category
end
```

NOTE: The number of nodes between the "High" and "Low" categories are variable. I need a way to dynamically add the hierarchical names.

But how do I go about indexing category names further up in the tree? I know I can't use methods 
in TS indexing, so how I do I setup the database?

Most importantly, how do I index the "high" category name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do this ?

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  indexes :name

  category = category.parent
  indexes category.name, as: :low_category

  while category.parent do
    if category.parent
      indexes category.name, as: :root_category
    elsif category.parent
      indexes category.name, as: :high_category
    else
      indexes category.name
    end

    category = category.parent
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes this would work for that specific case, but the number of nodes between the high and low category is variable. I need to generate these dynamically and separate the high category name from all the rest. Any way to do this in TS?

Comment: I changed my answer. It's probably not the better solution bu it should work.